# Why doesn't RVM work in a bash script like it works in an interactive shell?

Tags: bash, rvm

If you type the command in console, it works.

But if you put them in a bash script, problem comes.

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use 1.8.7
rvm list #  This shows the ruby used in parent shell's rvm.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the script you are most likely not loading rvm as a function.

http://rvm.io/rvm/basics/

Comment: Good catch, I completely missed that :-)

Comment: @guangnan: Perhaps you mean `type -t rvm`

Answer (score 8):

The shell functions installed by RVM aren't necessarily exported to subshells. In your shell script, you can re-initialize RVM with something like the same command line that's in your .bash_profile or .bashrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

After you do that, the rvm functions will be available within the shell script.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution that is given on the RVM site link that is given in he accepted answer. It worked form me!

Comment: I added this to my shell-script.  On the next line, I try "rvm use ..." and get the usual "Warning! PATH is not properly... rvm use... will not work" error.  What do we add to our shell-script to make RVM a function?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `echo -n START; rvm use 1.8.7 ; rvm list; echo -n END` without the `eval`, and see what it outputs. Everything between START and END will be executed as a command.

Comment: It still shows that 1.9.2 is selected. I found more clues and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [rvm documentation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/cli/), it sets up the *current shell*. When you execute a shell script, you are executing a *new shell process*. That new process dies when the script ends, so the updates made by `rvm` to your environment disappear.

To script this, you'll need to do something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use 1.8.7
exec /bin/bash
```

This will (hopefully) drop you into a shell process with the updated environment provided by `rvm`, and when you are finished, you can just `exit` from it to go back to your default environment.

Alternatively, you count set up an alias that will modify your current shell environment:

```
alias r187="rvm use 1.8.7"
```

Add that line to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` to have it stick around permanently. Any time you want to use `1.8.7`, type `r187`. You can set up other ones for different versions too, if you like.

Comment: Nop. It's more weired than that. The question is NOT the subprocess can't change the parent, the question is the subprocess can't even change itself !?

Comment: Does `rvm use` output anything when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `eval`, and if you still want it, you are using it incorrectly. I would recommend this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use 1.8.7
rvm list
```

But if you really want the `eval`, go with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval rvm use 1.8.7; rvm list
```

Comment: @dogbane Well look at that... I never knew about that one. I'll edit, but it still looks like the `eval` was not necessary.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear at first. I used `eval` for a reason that the command is actually from a String variable. However now it seems not `eval` related. Question updated.