# Bundler Trying To Run Under Wrong Version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04

I have a rails site, which I deploy via ssh using a git post-receive hook. When I ssh into the server and run bundle install it runs correctly under the specified ruby version of 2.2.2. However, when I push to the server from my local machine and it hits the 'bundle install command', I get the following:

```
hooks/post-receive: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I can't find for the life of me why it is pointing to ruby1.9.1. This directory does not exist. I do see a directory for ruby2.3 in that directory, but not ruby2.2.2 which is the correct directory. Something is quite fouled up, but I can't figure how to fix it. Anyone seen anything like this?

UPDATE: Here is my post-receive hook, as per the request below...

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_DIR=/home/deploy/www_production
WORK_TREE=/home/deploy/www
export MGOTS_DATABASE_USER='user'
export MGOTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD='pass'

export RAILS_ENV="production"
. ~/.bash_profile

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref = refs/heads/master ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE
        git --work-tree=$WORK_TREE --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE/shared/pids $WORK_TREE/shared/sockets $WORK_TREE/shared/log

        # start deploy tasks
        cd $WORK_TREE
        bundle install
        rake db:create
        rake db:migrate
        rake assets:precompile
        rake requests:cleanup
        sudo restart puma-manager
        sudo service nginx restart
        # end deploy tasks
        echo "Git hooks deploy complete"
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

UPDATE: For the sake of clarity, as the answer points to the correct place to find the answer, but doesn't state it exactly, I am posting my updated hook file here. You can see the difference between this one and the one above, and that is what solved the problem. Please note that the path to the rvm directory can be found by typing the command: which rvm - that's the one you want to point to.

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_DIR=/home/deploy/www_production
WORK_TREE=/home/deploy/www
export MGOTS_DATABASE_USER='user'
export MGOTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD='pass'

export RAILS_ENV="production"
export RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS="/home/deploy/.rvm/ruby-2.2.2@www/gems"

. ~/.bash_profile

[[ -s "/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref = refs/heads/master ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE
        git --work-tree=$WORK_TREE --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE/shared/pids $WORK_TREE/shared/sockets $WORK_TREE/shared/log

        # start deploy tasks
        cd $WORK_TREE
        bundle install
        rake db:create
        rake db:migrate
        rake assets:precompile
        rake requests:cleanup
        sudo restart puma-manager
        sudo service nginx restart
        # end deploy tasks
        echo "Git hooks deploy complete"
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

Comment: does your gemfile specify ruby version? If not put this in your gemfile ruby "2.2.2"

Comment: Yes, the opening of my gemfile has: source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.2"

Comment: your server has ruby 2.2.2 installed?

Comment: Yes, it does. And when I ssh into the server and command "which ruby" it gives me back 2.2.2

Comment: What is the remote ssh user u used in your local remote. And through which user u r logging in terminal

Comment: The user I ssh with is different than the user I am on terminal but this has not been an issue with any of my other rails sites

Comment: Found this, does it help you? https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260#issuecomment-177621474

Comment: The only solution I could find, originating from that thread was found at the rubygems-bundler page on github. However, it says that for versions of ruby over 2.2.0 I shouldn't use it, but instead should set the RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS environment variable. I did that and it made no difference. It's still giving me errors trying to use the 1.9.1 version, which is not installed on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load RVM functions to the shell script. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8493284/3134810)
Or just switch to Rbenv :)

Comment: The path indicated in the linked answer doesn't exist. I'm looking for a "scripts" folder, but can't find one. Could it be called something else?

Comment: I figured out where it is by running which rvm - trying now

Comment: This worked! I can't award the bounty for another 19 hours, but I will come back and award it.

Comment: I just awarded the bounty, but it didn't confirm anything so I'm not sure if it went through. Let me know if you don't get it.

Comment: Excellent - I posted the updated hook file above for anyone looking for exactly what was done.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your default ruby to use the version `2.2.2`

Are you using RVM? For RVM its: `rvm use --default 2.2.2`

Comment: can you share your git post-receive hook that you use for this?

Comment: Yes, @tenshiAMD - please see above. I have edited the question.